# Get suggestions on misspelled words in spell check (when have the squiggly red line)

Tags: auto-correct, spell-check

I get a red squiggly line under my misspelled words but when I touch on the line I get a menu with only the 2 choices of adding to the dictionary and to delete.

How can I get it to give me some options of correct spelling? I remember once before having this problem and I found a solution online. but now for the life of me I can't remember the solution and I cant seem to find it again online.